# Prestashop's new theme - Empty page or fatal error "call to a member function disable() on a non-object

Tags: prestashop, parallax, fatal-error, prestashop-1.6

I've bought Parallbag theme for Prestashop a few days ago (theme is for PS 1.6.0.x - my PS is 1.6.0.14). Prestashop works fine on default theme but when I switch it into Parallbag all I can see is a blank page. It works correctly only if I turn off **csthemeconfigurator** module, but it's the most important module and without it I can't see 98% of the page... If I install csthemeconfigurator via module's installator I will get this fatal error:
**[PrestaShop] Fatal error in module file :/home/virt106312/domains/tiympal.wirt17.bhlink.pl/public_html/prestashop/classes/module/Module.php:
Call to a member function disable() on a non-object**

it's this piece of code in Module.php file:

```
/**
     * This function disable module $name. If an $name is an array,
     * this will disable all of them
     *
     * @param array|string $name
     * @return true if succeed
     * @since 1.4.1
     */
    public static function disableByName($name)
    {
            // If $name is not an array, we set it as an array
            if (!is_array($name))
                    $name = array($name);
            $res = true;
            // Disable each module
            foreach ($name as $n)
                    if (Validate::isModuleName($n))
                            $res &= Module::getInstanceByName($n)->disable();
return $res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, it was due to a missing modules folder in the theme zip provided (in my case it was csbloglatestpost).

Check what modules are called for disabling (and enabling) in */modules/csthemeconfigurator/classes/csthemeconfiguratorClass.php* and make sure there are corresponding folders in your /modules directory.

If they are not present look into the others zip provided with the theme (the others homepage styles) I found my missing module folder there.